# MySQL, put first letter of title field into another field?

Tags: sql, mysql

I would like to select some data and put first letter of title field into another field. Is it possible?

```
auto
business
Sports
1st offer
```

I want to get something like that

```
a|auto
b|business
s|Sports
0|1st offer
```

0 = any non alphabetic character

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)

Answer (score 2):

try

`UPDATE table SET field = LEFT(title, 1);`

You may also want to use LOWER() to only get lowercase first letters. Use a condition to filter non-alphanumeric characters and assign "0" to field in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will get

> SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING( TITLE, 1 ,1),' ', TITLE)  from TITLE

returns

```
 a|auto
 b|business
 s|Sports
```